# How to find if user if fan of object in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, many-to-many, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have two models in my CakePHP app: `Company` and `User`. They are linked with a HABTM relationship. This creates a "like", so if a `User` is linked to a `Company` then that user likes that company.

How, if viewing a company profile page, can I check if the logged-in user likes the company? I fetch the company details in my controller action…

```
<?php
class CompaniesController {

    public function view($slug) {
        $company = $this->Company->findBySlug($slug);
        $this->set(array(
            'company' => $company,
            'is_fan' => ($this->Auth->loggedIn()) ? $this->Company->isFan($this->Auth->user('id')) : false
        ));
    }
}
```

My thoughts were to have an `isFan()` method in my `Company` model—as you can see above—that would take a user ID as a parameter. But I'm getting stuck as to what I'd actually put in this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Company

    public function isFan($userId, $companyId) {

        $found = $this->Company->CompanyUsers->find('first', array(
            'conditions'=>array(
                'CompanyUsers.user_id'=>$userId,
                'CompanyUsers.company_id'=>$companyId
            )
        );

        return $found != false;

     }

}
```

Basically, you query the HABTM join table to determine if the connection exists.